# MPI_Allgather segmentation fault cant send to receive buffer

Tags: c, mpi

I am currently trying to write a very simple program but can not seem to stop seg-faulting. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
   int my_id, num_procs;
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);

   int r1, r2;
   srand(time(NULL) * my_id);
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
      if(i == 0)
      {
         r1 = rand() % 100;
      }
      else{
         r2 = rand() % 100;
      }
   }

   printf("\nProcess #%i has numbers %i and %i \n",my_id,r1,r2);
   printf("\n");

   int sendArray[2];
   //Put the nubers in sendArray
   sendArray[0] = r1;
   sendArray[1] = r2;

   int size = 2 * num_procs;
   int rbuf[size];
   for(int i = 0;i < size;i++)
   {
      rbuf[i] = 0;
   }

   //rbuf = (int *)malloc(gsize*100*sizeof(int));
   //Use MPI_Allgather
   MPI_Allgather( sendArray, 2, MPI_INT, rbuf, size,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD ); //segfault HERE, must be using parameters incorrectly

   if(my_id == 0){
      printf("-------------------------------------\n");
   }

   //printf("\nProcess #%i has number %i in pos0\n",my_id,rbuf[0]);
   //printf("\nProcess #%i has number %i in pos1\n",my_id,rbuf[1]);
   //printf("\nProcess #%i has number %i in pos2\n",my_id,rbuf[2]);
   //printf("\nProcess #%i has number %i in pos3\n",my_id,rbuf[3]);

   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The idea is very basic. Create two random numbers within each process, store them in the send buffer, in my case - it's `sendArray`, then call MPI_Allgather to spread all the numbers to each process, where I am attempting to send the numbers to the receive buffer named `rbuf`. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here but this code most certainly segfaults where I call `MPI_Allgather`.

Comment: The receive count parameter expects the number of elements you receive _from each rank_ - that is, '2' and not 'size' in your case: MPI_Allgather(sendArray, 2, MPI_INT, rbuf, 2, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

Comment: Oh, that is an individual receive count not a total count. Sorry just read documentation again, you are correct I misinterpreted that to be the total received or something.

Comment: That worked, wow.. what a silly mistake. I was trying everything else literally, thank you @DavidBöhme

Comment: @DavidBöhme it is answer, thanks)